I am not able to import the powershell module Microsoft.Graph.Entra.Beta
I am not able to import the powershell module Microsoft.Graph.Entra.Beta.
I want to use Set-EntraBetaTrustFrameworkPolicy module to upload xml configs to Azure AD B2C as per this microsoft doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.entra.beta/set-entrabetatrustframeworkpolicy?view=entra-powershell-beta . And it requires the module Microsoft.Graph.Entra.Beta to be installed.
I am using this commands to install module :
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Entra.Beta -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
This is the error i see in the github action:
found in any module directory.
At D:\a\_temp\360a07d2-14b9-4abd-8843-bc54622430e9.ps1:22 char:1
+ Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Entra.Beta
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Microsoft.Graph.Entra.Beta:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand```


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.entra.beta/set-entrabetatrustframeworkpolicy?view=entra-powershell-beta



=======================Edit replying to Rukminis question=============
Are you able to do this also? I have created a service principle in Azure AD B2C and want to upload TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file to it using Set-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy powershell cmdlet in GHA. Everything in this works for me except the last line . I get an error Set-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy is not know cmdlet even though I am able to succesfully import Powershell AzureADPreview module without any issues. I am pulling my hair out to figure this out

```Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
az login --service-principal --username $service-principal-clientId --password $service-principal-password --tenant $tenantId --allow-no-subscriptions
$aadToken = az account get-access-token --resource-type aad-graph | ConvertFrom-Json
$graphToken = az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph | ConvertFrom-Json
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken.accessToken -AccountId $service-principal-clientId -TenantId $tenantId -MsAccessToken $graphToken.accessToken
Set-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy -Id B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions -InputFilePath .\Templates\TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml```


same issues with Connect-Entra PSCmdlet I have tried to install Microsoft.Graph module and run same command.. no luck. I have tried installing Microsoft.Graph.Entra and Microsoft.Graph.Entra.Beta and both dont get installed

To install and import the Microsoft.Graph.Entra.Beta, make use of below yml file:
name: Azure AD B2C Policy Upload

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  install-and-upload:
    runs-on: windows-latest  # Use a Windows runner
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3  # Checkout your repository code to access the PowerShell script

      - name: Install Microsoft.Graph.Entra.Beta module
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Entra.Beta -AllowPrerelease -Force -Scope CurrentUser
                   
      - name: Import the module
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
             Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Entra.Beta
             
      - name: Connect the module
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
             Connect-Entra


The modules installed and imported successfully like below:

The error "Not found in any module directory" usually occurs if there is any issue with PowerShell connection. Make use of shell: pwsh and use the above yml file to install and import modules.

that worked. Are you able to run this snippet as well?

Which snippet??

I have added the snippet in the original question itself.. I was not able to add in the comments as it has 555 max characters allowed

Please post it as a new question with all the details and paste it here will help you there:)

Hi @Rukmini! Thanks a ton for your help.. this is the new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79279207/set-azureadmstrustframeworkpolicy-powershell-cmdlet-works-on-laptop-but-not-in-g

Sure will check:)
